# Event handler works partially

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I create in a class of a WPF application two identical circles and I want to assign the same event to both of them. However only on one of them the event hander works while on the other not. I tried to implement the same event handler with two different names but still the same happens. What could a potential problem in respect of the following code?

```
SmallCircle leftCircle1 = new InputCircle(Brushes.Yellow, 7, 7);
Ellipse s1Ellipse = leftCircle1.thisEllipse; 
rectCanvas.Children.Add(s1Ellipse);
SmallCircle leftCircle2 = new InputCircle(Brushes.Yellow, 7, 7);
Ellipse s2Ellipse = leftCircle2.thisEllipse;
rectCanvas.Children.Add(s2Ellipse);

s1Ellipse.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(input_MouseLeftButtonDown1);
s2Ellipse.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(input_MouseLeftButtonDown1);
s3Ellipse.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(output_MouseLeftButtonDown1);    


 private void output_MouseLeftButtonDown1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        rectCanvas.MouseLeftButtonDown -= Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        rectCanvas.MouseLeftButtonUp -= Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp;
        rectCanvas.MouseMove -= Canvas_MouseMove;


        nodeComb.lineCreated = true;
        Point StartPosition = e.GetPosition(sender as UIElement);
        nodeComb.initialPoint = StartPosition;

    }

    private void input_MouseLeftButtonDown1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (nodeComb.lineCreated == true)
        {
            Point EndPosition = e.GetPosition(sender as UIElement);
            nodeComb.endingPoint = EndPosition;
            nodeComb.createLine();
            nodeComb.lineCreated = false;
        }

    }
```

In particular, s2Ellipse event handler works, while s1Ellipse does not.

[image: The Gui]

Only the bottom input circle (s2) listens to handler, the above does not.
Really very strange!

Comment: Why would you expect the event to be fired by s1 too?

Comment: I want both shapes to "listen" to the same event, in order to draw a line ending to any of them? Even when I change their order, only s2 fires.

Comment: can you show an image of the resultant GUI?

Comment: I've created a simple project with 2 ellipses sharing the same click event handler and it works. Id that all you're looking for? Why do you unsubscribe from teh MouseDown event?

Comment: Is it that you want *both* ellipses to receive an event when either of them is clicked?

Comment: No, I want each shape individually to receive an event, which happens to be the same for the two shapes. But the problem actually is that the upper circle cannot receive an event at all, even when I try another one.

Comment: Hmm. What happens if you change the order in which the ellipses are added to the canvas?

Comment: I have already tried this and nothing is changed. Very strange.

Comment: What are the second and third arguments of the `InputCircle` constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I lost finally the problem. I add a textbox on the bottom half of the rectangle which contains the name of each rectangle. This had an adequate width to cover the small input circle, so as the mouse event handler not to apply to the upper circle. I just trimmed its width and the handler applies to both circles. Really deceptive...